# Local variable naming convention with JS Lint

Tags: javascript, jslint

Industry standard for most locally scoped variables is an '_' but JS Lint complains mightily about these _'s.

Does anyone else have a naming convention for locally scoped variables in a JavaScript file

Comment: Don't believe everything on the internet, especially not JSLint. It can be a helpful tool to find errors, but Crockford is rather keen on conventions he ‘invented’, like discouraging the use of `++` and `--`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

We develop in .NET here, and made the simple decision to standardize on a simple convention. C# and JavaScript code should be as close to one another as possible.

Hence, camelCase for local variables, TitleCase for types, and so on.

It's actually worked out pretty well, since there's no jarring transition between the two languages, and it does a great job of distinguishing *our* code from native JS code and that of 3rd party libraries.

My 2 cents.

P.S. We use the StyleCop standards, FWIW. And they probably won't make JSLint any happier.

Comment: Agreed. "Standards are great... there's so many to choose from!"